# MonoTouch for iPad: How to replace +/- sign in UIStepper with an image?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want to use UIStepper to represent back/forward buttons. I'd like to replace the standard +/- sign with arrow images. How can I do that in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately....not really, without using private APIs. If you take a look at UIStepper's view hierarchy it's just two UIButton's with their own BackgroundImage's for their given UIControlState + an UIImageView for the overall stepper's background.

It'd be much easier and safer to implement your own UIStepper or try and port someone else's obj-C UIStepper implementation then to try and override the existing images. That being said, I went through the motions of trying to verify that it was possible by touching the view hierarchy directly:

```
public class Stepper : UIStepper
{
    UIImageView _BackgroundImageView;

    public Stepper()
        : base()
    {
        _BackgroundImageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile(AppImage.Strechable_Black_Button_Normal));
    }

    public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        //This sets the background UIImageView;
        _BackgroundImageView.Frame = this.Subviews[0].Frame;
        this.Subviews[0] = _BackgroundImageView;

        //Set the background image for the two UIButton's here
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I found that instead of UIStepper, I could use UISegmentedControl and it acutally works great.

Answer (score 2):

```
[stepper setIncrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BUTTON_PLUS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[stepper setDecrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BUTTON_MINUS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```